# facebook debugger URL returned a bad HTTP response code

Tags: facebook

I've created a shop site for one my customer.

Facebook debugger send to me many errors:

```
Could Not Follow Redirect Path Using data from 
http://www.yupeshop.it/IT/prodotto.php?id=84&label=Sciarpa+Stampa+con+fantasia+UK 
because there was an error following the redirect path.
```

But there is no redirect. URL returned a bad HTTP response code.

But if I try to get the page with an online check I see 200 OK as answer, what's wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the OG meta tags, you have given

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.yupeshop.it/prodotto.php?id=84" />
```

And that URL, which you are telling Facebook is the “real” URL to use for this object, currently only returns a 404 Not Found.

(I guess that is actually meant to be http://www.yupeshop.it/IT/prodotto.php?id=84 with the directory IT in it as well?)