# 401 Authorization Required on Facebook Share

Tags: facebook, authorization, facebook-share

I've just created a Thank You page for a completed product purchase and implemented some pretty cool responsive social sharing buttons via http://kurtnoble.com/labs/rrssb/

I'm pretty stoked with the buttons but I'm getting a 401 Authorization Required error upon sharing the page via Facebook.  All the other buttons work accordingly.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

http://viraone.com/thank-you

I have the following open graph tags in the header..

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Good Stuff from Viraone" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.viraone.com/thank-you" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.viraone.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/facebook-share.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Good Stuff is the first step to getting energized and focused. It’s raw, vegan, gluten-free, 95% organic/wildcrafted, and non-GMO." />
```

Any ideas of what's causing this?  I previously had the sites folder under password protection on the server, but I've since removed this (5 days ago) and I'm still having this error.

Comment: Did you run the page through Facebook's debug tool to see what Facebook is getting when the URL is accessed? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: @Igy Thanks for the tip! I haven't done much with FB integrations yet so I wasn't aware I could use their debug tool.  Turns out I was getting an 'URL returned a bad HTTP response code.' I found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540738/facebook-debugger-url-returned-a-bad-http-response-code) on SO and figured out it was my 'og:url' meta from FB's Open graph.  I was missing the trailing bracket on my url `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.viraone.com/thank-you/" />`after the end of thank-you.  So that took care of the bad HTTP response.

Comment: But I'm still getting the 401 error.  Perhaps I need to setup an facebook App and place the ID in the header as well?  Any confirmation on that being the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,so this issue was my link address for the sharing button.
Previously it read

```
<a class="popup" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://viraone.com/"> <span class="text">facebook</span></a>
```

but this was what was generating the 401, my misunderstanding was that this part of the URL post '?' was supposed to be what URL was shared to FB, but that's not the case. This is the URL from which the sharing originates hence, because I was running this from my Thank You page the correct sharing button should read..

```
<a class="popup" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://viraone.com/thank-you/"> <span class="text">facebook</span>
```

Hope my fussing about helps somebody else too!